# Does anyone know an expression that could substitute for "not my first rodeo"?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, cliche

Context: stageplay dialogue.  Trying to think of an idiom/expression that's less of a cliche. 
Please and thank you...

Comment: You want another cliche, but you don't want it to be a cliche? Perhaps you mean that common, existing expressions for the same thing may vary in *degree* of "clicheness", but it's hard to imagine how one would measure that.

Comment: Correct, looking for a less popular expression.  I actually have a specific expression in mind, but it's not exactly on the tip of my tongue.  "not my first rodeo" isn't a perfect match to what I'm trying to recall, but it's the closest.  Subtext: "[the occurence] wasn't my first time and likely won't be my last."

Comment: "wasn't born yesterday", "don't teach your grandmother to suck eggs","not my first beer", "I have done this once or twice before"

Comment: I am not a noob. I wasn't born yesterday. I know the drill. Don't teach grandma to suck eggs. Like come on, there's like a hundred expressions that spring to mind.

Comment: I was born at night... but it wasn't last night

Comment: This phrase Googles well; my favorite alternative is "Not my first zombie apocalypse"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiom ***"since you were in diapers"*** can work if the speaker is significantly older than the addressee:

> I've been [going to rodeos] since you were in diapers.

You can insert any other colorful phrase associated with infancy if you prefer: "since you were in short pants";  "since you were watching Teletubbies";  "since you were sucking on your mother's breast".  This last one is a bit crude, and can be made even cruder using vulgar slang if it's appropriate for the tone of the piece.

(I'm aware, of course, that you're not talking about literal rodeos.  The phrase in brackets should be replaced with whatever's appropriate in context.)

Comment: You guys are great... thank you!  "Not my first beer" is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

**not born yesterday**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+born+yesterday) idiom

> experienced; knowledgeable in the ways of the world.

As in:

> I know what's going on. I wasn't born yesterday. Sally knows the
>   score. She wasn't born yesterday.